# Generate random numbers, letters or characters within a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random, data-masking

I'm in the middle of a data anonymization for SQL Server.

I have this 3 formulas that help me create what I want:

```
SELECT CHAR(cast((90 - 65) * rand() + 65 AS INTEGER)) -- only letters
SELECT CAST((128 - 48) * RAND() + 48 AS INTEGER) -- only numbers
SELECT CHAR(CAST((128 - 48) * RAND() + 48 AS INTEGER)) -- letters, numbers, symbols
```

However, this only can create **1 number** or **1 letter** or **1 symbol**.

I want to have the freedom that allows me to create a random string or number of the length I want. Like **3 or 5 numbers**, **3 or 5 letters**, **3 or 5 between numbers, letters or symbols**.

I also have found something very close to what I want:

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(100)), 3) -- letters and numbers
```

this is a very smart idea because uses `NEWID()` and it allows me to create a random sequence of numbers and letters of the length I want (3 in this case). But symbols are missing.

I need 3 different `SELECT`:

- One for numbers only
- One for letters only
- One for numbers, letters and symbols

With the freedom of choice about the length of the data.

Comment: Just for completeness, you have established that [dynamic data masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking) won't meet your needs, right? Otherwise it'd be a shame to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Part 1/2: I have two posts in my blog with a copy as articles at Microsoft site (you can choose if read from my blog or from Microsoft site) exactly on this. First one title: `T-SQL: Random String` and shows multiple way to build random string in TSQL, and the second one named: `SQL Server: Create Random String Using CLR` and presents code using SQLCLR. Both are very old from 2013 so maybe we can add more tricks now and improve them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I've already deployed Dynamic Data Masking and I tried to push that in more than one meeting. It was rejected every time because the managers could not understand how it works and they were afraid to open the server for remote login. I'm fuming

Comment: @RonenAriely, just paste the link in the comment

Comment: Hi @FrancescoMantovani `:-)` This can work. (1) Using CLR: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21219.sql-server-create-random-string-using-clr.aspx (2) Using TSQL: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21196.t-sql-random-string.aspx

Comment: Note that these are Wiki articles, which anyone can add more options (solutions) if you find such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some work required for a complete solution but here's the workings of an idea you might want to experiment with further, if you still need it:

```
declare @type varchar(10)='letters', @length tinyint=5;

with chars as (
    select top(59) 31 + Row_Number() over (order by (select 1)) n from master.dbo.spt_values
), s  as (
    select top (@length) Char(n.n) c
    from chars n
    where @type='all' 
    or (@type='symbols' and n between 33 and 47)
    or (@type='numbers' and n between 48 and 57)
    or (@type='letters' and n between 65 and 90)
    order by newid()
)
select String_Agg(s.c,'') 
from s
```

Comment: Solid approach.  Just a thought...  Include a UNION ALL (or two) to allow repeating characters.  +1

Comment: Indeed and I considered that, if getting repetitive characters was desirable could just make the number list arbitrarily long and use a modulo to get a repeating range. Assumed as the OP only suggested a length of a few characters it probably wasn't important, but could be added with more clarity.

Comment: jaw dropping good. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Recursive query might work with rand() function:

```
declare @desiredlength tinyint=5;

With builder As (
    Select *
    From (Values (0, '', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789')) initial (length, randstr, pool)
  Union All
    Select length+1, randstr + substring(pool,cast(rand()*len(pool)+1 AS int),1), pool
    From builder
    Where length<@desiredlength
)
Select randstr From builder
Where length=@desiredlength
```

rand() in a single select returns the same random number in each row of a select.  But here in a recursive select you're in a grey area where each recursion might be treated like a separate query.

Obviously you can tailor the pool definition to be any character set you want and the rest of the code will choose from whatever's there.

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'builder'.`

Comment: Sorry, sql server does not use the recursive keyword.  Corrected that and changed the first Select to use a From (Values) syntax.

Comment: `Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Argument data type float is invalid for argument 2 of substring function.`

Comment: Ah, Sql Server does not automatically cast to int.  I made it explicit.

Comment: `Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "randstr" of recursive query "builder".`

Comment: OK I'm stumped.  The only thing I can think of is the '' in the initializer needs a Cast() to Varchar.  Instead of '', write cast('' AS varchar).